# firebase firestore emulator not serving updated data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been struggling with this issue for a while, any help would be very much welcomed.

I have a TS/JS application which accesses firestore through the v9 version of the SDK. When my application is running and connected to the emulator, I cannot see updates to collections.  When I connect my application to a regular firestore instance (i.e., not using the emulator) it works just fine.

When connected to the emulator I can read from the collection, i can write to the collection, however when I try to read any new or updated records from the collection it appears to only serve records from cache.  I've tried to force it to read from "server" but nothing I've tried works.  It works just fine when I connect the application to an actual firestore instance and note the emulator.

Am I doing something?  Is this a known issue?  I've seen references to getting realtime updates, but this is not my usecase. I would like to be able to make a call to get the updated records.

```
const fetchAll = async (): Promise<any[]> => {
  const results: any[] = [];
  const refs = collection(db, COLLECTION.REPORTS);

  const queryRefs = query(refs, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(queryRefs);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => results.push(doc.data()));

  return results;
};
```

Comment: Please include the following: firebase.json config, the TS/JS code you're using to connect to the emulator, the config you're using to initialize your app. When starting the emulators, are you passing in a --project flag? if not, what is the default selected project when running `firebase use`?